# Determine the version of asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, web, version

i'm using visual studio 2015 and developing asp.net website.
now i decided to publish my website and define website version manually.
can i Determine the version of the website Manually?
Like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHcE3.jpg)(this image is properties of windows application but in website properties there isn't publish version) .

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for asking your first question! Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a moment and consider adding some examples of what you've already tried, and what issues you may of had. You'll get a better answer with a better question ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to define website(or any other applications) version manually, you need to specify that in AssemlyInfo.cs. There are two tags in assemlyinfo.cs names as [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]. You can specify your verion number in those tags.